# Import result html file (contain js code) to mysql using php

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I am try to get my location using javascript, but when i click submit data not entered to page action.php

> geolocation.php

```
<form action="action.php" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="lat" id="geolocation"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script>
var z = document.getElementById("geolocation");
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
function showPosition(position) { z.innerHTML = position.coords.latitude + "&lng=" + position.coords.longitude; }
</script>
```

> action.php

```
<?php
$lat = $_POST['lat'];
$lng = $_POST['lng'];

include 'koneksi.php'; 

mysqli_query($koneksi,"
INSERT INTO 
`data`(lat,lng)
VALUES
('$lat','$lng') ") or die ("ERROR WHEN INSERTING 1 OR DUPLICATE VALIDATE");
?>
```

Comment: undefined index `lng`, SQL injection is an another story

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you send form data to PHP with the POST method, it reads each field's **value** attribute, not its HTML.

You can create two hidden fields and set their `value`s in JavaScript, like this:

```
<form action="location.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="lat" id="latitude"><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="lng" id="longitude"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<script>
    const latitude = document.getElementById("latitude");
    const longitude = document.getElementById("longitude");
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);

    function showPosition(position) {
        latitude.value = position.coords.latitude;
        longitude.value = position.coords.longitude;
    }
</script>
```

Also be aware that if you don't validate user input, and don't use prepared statements, that you're vulnerable to SQL injections.

Answer (score 0):

Input field values are set via `.value`, not `.innerHTML`. What you want, is

```
function showPosition(position) { z.value = …; }
```

But if you want both values easily accessible via $_POST on the server side, you need to use two input fields to begin with. Right now you are sending both lat and long as *one* value, so you would have to take it apart on the server side again.